# Are there going to be specific tags for every language?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is PLDI going to include specific tags for every programming language?

Comment: Do you mean public languages that someone is using in the question, or languages under development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

Questions asking about why a specific or how a specific language implemented a feature would benefit from having a language specific tag